# How to perform != or <> in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

i need to fetch the table1 content which is not present in the table2 i dont think which is possible by <> or != operator so can any one help me here

```
select t1._id, t1."categoryName", t1.company_id, t1.active from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1._id <> t2.category_id 
inner join table3 t3 on t2 .department_id <> t3 ._id where  t3._id = 1
```

for example:
a collage can have 10 departments ,  students enrolled to 5 department which is present 1 collage 
table1 is dept
table 3 is col
table 2 looks like this:

```
col_id| dept_id   | student_id
1     |    1      |     1
1     |    2      |     2
1     |    3      |     3
1     |    4      |     4
1     |    5      |     5
```

i need to fetch rest of the dept_id which is not present in table 2

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question do not post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: You are looking for `NOT EXISTS` or the simpler `NOT IN`. You can also use an anti join as shown by Vao Tsun, but you'd usually only use this when the aforementioned straight-forward methods result in performance issues in your DBMS (which is not likely to happen in a DBMS as advanced as PostgreSQL). Please explain how table3 comes into play.

Comment: i have edited my question please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yep i got a solution to my question from dbastackexchange this might help others so pasting here

```
select
    cat._id,
    cat.cat_name
from
    cat
where
    not exists(
        select
            *
        from
            deptcat
            inner join dept on(
                dept._id = deptcat.dept_id
            )
        where
            deptcat.cat_id = cat._id
            and dept._id = 1
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

> i need to fetch the table1 content which is not present in the table2

Use a `not exists` query, something like this:

```
select * 
from table1 t1
where not exists (select *
                  from table2 t2
                  where t1._id = t2.category_id)
```

Note sure how table3 relates to the question "not present in table2"

Answer (score 0):

try not in, or outer join, like here:

```
select t1._id, t1."categoryName", t1.company_id, t1.active 
from table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on t1._id = t2.category_id 
left outer join table3 t3 on t2 .department_id = t3 ._id 
where  t3._id = 1
and t2.category_id is null
and t3 ._id is null
```

Comment: i dont have any NULL value in the table :(

Comment: nulls are result of outer join. they will be added. so when you seelct where other tables have null, you select only missing part. try?..

Comment: then I did not understand  a question I suppose. what about `not exists()`?.. and please pus some data samples and expected result to the post

Comment: i have updated my question please check and do needful thank you